# How to read file every Nth character the fastest way possible?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, performance

I already know a couple of ways to read a file every Nth characters in bash:

```bsh
LC_ALL=C
while read -n100 character; do
    echo "$character"
done < <(cat "$@" | tr -d '\n')
    echo "$character
```

But while this works, i wish to know faster ways to do this, in either Bash, or using posix/unix tools.

Any other way to do this faster?

Comment: Yes, write a C program doing that. See [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and use megabyte sized and aligned buffers. Consider also [dd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) and read [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [posix_fadvise(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html)

Comment: Why not assembly then ?

Comment: @GilesQuenot: because it is not worth the trouble. Most of the time could happen in kernel land.

Comment: You may attract more answers if you could give a minimal working example from which we might understand what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @NordineLotfi: please explain in your question why does that matters to you, and why you cannot write some code in C or in Python.

Answer (score 4):

Replicating [AdminBee's result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593657/116858) with somewhat simpler code.

The input data is the same as theirs:

```
12345678901234
567890123
4567890123456789012
34567890123
```

Every 10th character, starting at 10:

```
$ fold -w 1 file | awk 'NR % 10 == 0'
0
0
0
0
0
```

Same, but starting at 1:

```
$ fold -w 1 file | awk 'NR % 10 == 1'
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Same, but starting at 2:

```
$ fold -w 1 file | awk 'NR % 10 == 2'
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

In terms of performance, this is comparable to AdminBee's `awk` solution, but ever so slightly faster on large inputs ("large inputs" == the above test data repeated many times).

`fold -w 1` produces a single line per character in the input, discarding newlines.  Both the commands used are standard POSIX utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `awk` solution, which works with many but not all `awk` implementations due to using the "empty field separator" extension:

```
awk -F "" -v l=100 '{last=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ((i+carry)%l==0) {print $i; last=i}};\
                     if (last) {carry=NF-last} else {carry+=(NF-l)}}' inputfile.txt
```

This will treat every character as a single field (`-F ""`) and print only those fields where the field number modulo "skip length" `l` (in your case, 100) is zero, while taking into account carry-over but disregarding newlines.

Note that since it starts counting at 1, the first character is *not* read. You can use

```
awk -F "" -v l=10 -v ofs=1 '{last=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ((i+carry)%l==ofs) {print $i; last=i}};\
                             if (last) {carry=NF-last+ofs} else {carry+=(NF-l)}}' inputfile.txt
```

to adjust the offset via `ofs`.

#### Test case

Tested with `gawk`, `mawk` and `nawk` on a Linux system.

- Input file

  ```
  12345678901234
  567890123
  4567890123456789012
  34567890123
  ```
- Output "every 10th, starting with the 10th character"

  ```
  $ awk -F "" -v l=10 '{last=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ((i+carry)%l==0) {print $i; last=i}}; if (last) {carry=NF-last} else {carry+=(NF-l)}}' testfile.txt 
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  ```
- Output "every 10th, starting with the first character"

  ```
  $ awk -F "" -v l=10 -v ofs=1 '{last=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ((i+carry)%l==ofs) {print $i; last=i}}; if (last) {carry=NF-last+ofs} else {carry+=(NF-l)}}' testfile.txt 
  1
  1
  1
  1
  1
  1
  ```

Comment: @αғsнιη Since the algorithm disregards newlines, the behaviour should be the same as if `tr -d '\n'` had been issued prior to the `awk` call. As for the empty FS, I explicitly added a warning that this is not standard. It worked in my tests (although I used 10, not 100, for ease of creating test files), using `gawk`,`mawk` and `nawk` on a Linux system.